Ubuntu 24.04 LTS freezes and nothing works, force shutdown option left
sir this system is running
Intel® Core™ i5-6400 × 4
RAM 8GB
its showing disk 832.2 GB
GPU 610 i dont know as it says NVIDIA 610
i just installed ubuntu and running it, i did nothing in terms of drive research
the system just freezes randomly only otion left is to force shutdown

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Same issue with CPU: 13th Gen Intel i9-13900H, GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Max-Q, with driver version 535-proprietary, found a solution here https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1dbt03y/comment/l9ah2us/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
